# facebook sharing on servlet, jsp; getting auth code;

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, servlets, restfb

```
    public FacebookConnector() {
    try {
        FacebookClient.AccessToken token = getFacebookUserToken("???", "http://localhost:8083/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/");
        String accessToken = token.getAccessToken();
        Date expires = token.getExpires();
        fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(this.accessToken, Version.LATEST);
        myuser = fbClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
        mypage = fbClient.fetchObject(pageID, Page.class);
        counter = 0;
    } catch (Exception ex) {     //So that you can see what went wrong
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);  //in case you did anything incorrectly
    }
}

public void makeTestPost() {
    FacebookType publishMessageResponse = fbClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "Test from Graph API"));
    System.out.println("Published message ID: " + publishMessageResponse.getId());
}

private FacebookClient.AccessToken getFacebookUserToken(String code, String redirectUrl) throws IOException {
    String appId = "My App Id";
    String secretKey = "My Secret Key";

    WebRequestor wr = new DefaultWebRequestor();
    WebRequestor.Response accessTokenResponse = wr.executeGet(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
            + "&client_secret=" + secretKey + "&code=" + code);

    return DefaultFacebookClient.AccessToken.fromQueryString(accessTokenResponse.getBody());
}
```

I am working on enabling facebook sharing for my application that is built on JSP and servlet.

I am using above code.

I need your inputs on 2 things:
1) If my approach is correct.
2) How to get auth code? So that can help me in getting authentication token.

Help of any sort is appreciated. Thanks. AY

Comment: guys, who ever is down flagging the post. Can you please comment or suggest what is wrong with this so that I can improve? Please don't waste the attention this post should get by down flagging this.

Comment: I have no experience with JSP servlets but I found this on google: http://codifyit.blogspot.com/2010/12/integrate-your-web-site-with-facebook.html Maybe the flagging was because this question is too obvious and you might be able to find more info just googling. Again, I'm not an expert here, just trying to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

For facebook authentication you can do like that:-

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?+client_id=YourAPPID&scope=email,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_likes,user_photos,user_tagged_places,user_friends,user_posts,publish_actions,read_page_mailboxes,user_actions.music,user_tagged_places,user_status,user_website,manage_pages,read_custom_friendlists&redirect_uri=<%=URLEncoder.encode("Your Redirect URL")%>">Click</a>
```

It will generate code then use this code to send request to graph.facebook as you written correctly in your code then it will generate accesscode and use accesscode as per your requirement